# Data from another column with np.select

Tags: pandas, numpy

How to make conditional column using df['column'].str.extract() for choises in np.select() ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['--extract_text--','--extract_text--','--extract_text--','--extract_text--'],'column2':['A','A','B','B']})

conditions = [df['column2'].str.contains('A',case=False,na=False)]
choises = [df['column1'].str.extract('--(.*)--')]

df['new'] = np.select(conditions,choises)
```

If I try to use code, I get

```
KeyError: 'new'
```

But if I add column like

```
df['new'] = 'a'
```

and then use it all, I got all column with choises but without conditions:

```
            column1 column2           new
0  --extract_text--       A  extract_text
1  --extract_text--       A  extract_text
2  --extract_text--       B  extract_text
3  --extract_text--       B  extract_text
```

but I expect

```
            column1 column2           new
0  --extract_text--       A  extract_text
1  --extract_text--       A  extract_text
2  --extract_text--       B  a
3  --extract_text--       B  a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what might help is specifying `expand=False` argument inside of `str.extract()`

```py
conditions = [df['column2'].str.contains('A',case=False,na=False)]
choises = [df['column1'].str.extract('--(.*)--', expand=False)]

df['new'] = np.select(conditions,choises)
```

```
    column1 column2 new
0   --extract_text--    A   extract_text
1   --extract_text--    A   extract_text
2   --extract_text--    B   0
3   --extract_text--    B   0
```

---

you could do the same with `np.where` if you don't like `0` values in `df['new']`.

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['column2'].str.contains('A',case=False,na=False), \
                     df['column1'].str.extract('--(.*)--', expand=False), \
                     '')
```

```
    column1 column2 new
0   --extract_text--    A   extract_text
1   --extract_text--    A   extract_text
2   --extract_text--    B   
3   --extract_text--    B
```